# Wrapping several XML files into a single XML file with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml

I have a bunch of XML files that look like this:

```
<widget>
    ...
</widget>
```

In PHP, I need to combine them into a single XML file like so:

```
<widgets>
    <widget>
        ...
    </widget>
    <widget>
        ...
    </widget>
    <widget>
        ...
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

This is trivial to do with `glob` and `file_[get/put]_contents`, but I'd like to do it properly with DOMDocument because there's more to it than this. I've created a `DOMDocument` instance and a wrapping element, and in a loop, use `appendChild()` to append each XML file inside said element. Unfortunately I keep getting a variety of errors thrown and I just can't put something together that works. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you are trying and the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use DOMDocument to load the other files, they will need to be valid XML files in their own right - ie have a single root node. Once you have that, the following code should work:

```
// Given that $files is a list of file names of xml files to add
// Each xml file must be xml conformant - ie a single root node
$dest = new DOMDocument;
$root = $dest->createElement ('widgets');
$dest->appendChild ($root);

foreach ($files as $fn)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument ();
    if  ($doc->load ($fn))
    {
        foreach ($doc->documentElement->childNodes as $child)
        {
            //  Copy deep for destination document
            $child = $dest->importNode ($child, true);
            $root->appendChild ($child);
        }
    }
}
```